# Custom label on secondary y-axis in R

Tags: r, plot

How can I put a custom label on the secondary y-axis in R using the following code?

```
library(zoo)
#--------------random data
x.Date <- as.Date(paste(2003, 02, c(1, 3, 7, 9, 14), sep = "-"))
z <- zoo(rnorm(5), x.Date)
z2 <- zoo(rnorm(5, sd = 0.2), x.Date)

#--------------create plot
png(filename = "Google.png", width = 480, height = 480) 

plot(z, type="l", xlab="Year", lt=1, lwd=1, ylab="Google Trend")
grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL, col = "lightgray", lty = "dotted",
     lwd = par("lwd"), equilogs = TRUE)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(z2, type="l", ann=FALSE, lt=1, lwd=3, yaxt="n")
axis(4, ylab="Test")  # Here?!

legend("topright", c("z", "z2"), lty=c(1,1), 
    lwd=c(1,3),col=c("black","black"),
    box.col="black",bg="white")

title("Google")
dev.off()
```

The label "Test" does not appear in my plot...

Furthermore, how to overwrite the gridlines with the z2 and the z lines? In other words, how to bring the plotted lines to the "front"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `mtext` for this to work:

```
library(zoo)
#--------------random data
x.Date <- as.Date(paste(2003, 02, c(1, 3, 7, 9, 14), sep = "-"))
z <- zoo(rnorm(5), x.Date)
z2 <- zoo(rnorm(5, sd = 0.2), x.Date)

#--------------create plot
#png(filename = "Google.png", width = 480, height = 480) 

plot(z, type="l", xlab="Year", lt=1, lwd=1, ylab="Google Trend")
grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL, col = "lightgray", lty = "dotted",
     lwd = par("lwd"), equilogs = TRUE)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(z2, type="l", ann=FALSE, lt=1, lwd=3, yaxt="n")
axis(4)  

#------here is the only part I added
#you specify the text, location and usually line=2 to place next to 
#the y-axis labels
mtext('Test', side=4, line=2)
#-----------------------------------    

legend("topright", c("z", "z2"), lty=c(1,1), 
       lwd=c(1,3),col=c("black","black"),
       box.col="black",bg="white")

title("Google")
#dev.off()
```

Output:

[image]

As for z and z2 they dont seem to be behind the gridlines here.

Comment: Well, thanks for this fast answer! What is odd though: It doesn't work if I create the plot.
The z line is behind the gridline though...

Comment: I can only see "Test" if I use `line=0` or `line=1` but then it is at the wrong spot.

Comment: Try changing the margins of both plots using `par(mar=c(5,4,4,2)` (use this before the plot function) and see which one works best for you. This is typical when using rstudio's viewer and png. Each value corresponds to each side of the plot. Increase the numbers to narrow down the plots so that you can see the label.

Comment: `c(5,4,4,2)` are the default values. Try increasing the numbers.

Comment: Thanks! Almost there. I now have the issue that the font size is wrong for "Test". Furthermore, there is a LOT of white space on the right side, even if I use the default values for margins.

Comment: Specificly the 4rth arg  to the mar-parameter.

Comment: To fix this add `cex=5` or whatever size font you want at the `mtext` function.

Comment: `cex=...` helps! Thanks for that. The only remaining issue is now this huge white space next to my plot if I use `win.metafile()` (default console I use)

Comment: I havent used `win.metafile` ever but I suppose the `width` might solve this.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The plot width will be reduced proportionally. But this annoying empty space on the right side stays...

Comment: I wish i could help about this one... I suggest you post a different question about this one and I am sure someone else will be able to help